# How to put the first word of the following page in a footer? Latex/LuaLatex

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex

I'd like to place the first word on a page in the footer of the preceding page.  The purpose being is for someone reading the paper aloud can see what the next word on the following page is going to be without having to turn the page.  I know this sounds odd - but this is the specification and I can't find any clues as to how TeX can give me a reference as to the words being shipped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `continue` package. For example:

```
% continueprob.tex SE 577702
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[word,allpages]{continue} \renewcommand{\flagend}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\textheight}{0.5\textheight}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Read the documentation (`> texdoc continue`) to see how to control the results.

Comment: Thank you!  In all the searching I have done I did not come across that. Much appreciated.